# Java HTTPS server code failing

Tags: java, ssl, https, server

I've been trying to implement a HTTPS/SSL server in Java, and I've tried using a number of different code examples, but they all seem to fail at the point that the server has read the request.  Below is one example I've been working with, and when I run that with Firefox, I get this error:

```
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 73 A7 11 73   AE 3C 41 C5 91 C7 E9 19  ....s..s.<A.....
Padded plaintext before ENCRYPTION:  len = 16
0000: 14 00 00 0C 73 A7 11 73   AE 3C 41 C5 91 C7 E9 19  ....s..s.<A.....
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 40
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 1
main, Exception while waiting for close java.net.SocketException: Software         caused connection abort: recv failed
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Software caused     connection abort: recv failed
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256]
 Priv exp --- null
 Exception occurred .... java.net.SocketException: Software caused     connection abort: recv failed
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.sendChangeCipherSpec(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.sendChangeCipherAndFinish(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.clientFinished(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at SSLServer.main(SSLServer.java:65)
```

and, here's the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.PrivilegedActionException;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import com.sun.net.ssl.*;
import com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider;

/**
 * @author Joe Prasanna Kumar
 * This program simulates an SSL Server listening on a specific port for client requests
 * 
 * Algorithm:
 * 1. Regsiter the JSSE provider
 * 2. Set System property for keystore by specifying the keystore which contains the server certificate
 * 3. Set System property for the password of the keystore which contains the server certificate
 * 4. Create an instance of SSLServerSocketFactory
 * 5. Create an instance of SSLServerSocket by specifying the port to which the SSL Server socket needs to bind with
 * 6. Initialize an object of SSLSocket
 * 7. Create InputStream object to read data sent by clients
 * 8. Create an OutputStream object to write data back to clients.
 * 
 */ 


public class SSLServer {

/**
 * @param args
 */

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    int intSSLport = 4443; // Port where the SSL Server needs to listen for new requests from the client

    {
        // Registering the JSSE provider
        Security.addProvider(new Provider());

        //Specifying the Keystore details
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore","C:\\Users\\test\\Eclipse-workspaces\\Test\\newkeystore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword","changeit");

        // Enable debugging to view the handshake and communication which happens between the SSLClient and the SSLServer
        System.setProperty("javax.net.debug","all");
    }

    try {
            // Initialize the Server Socket
            SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketfactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory)SSLServerSocketFactory.getDefault();
            SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket)sslServerSocketfactory.createServerSocket(intSSLport);
            SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket)sslServerSocket.accept();

            // Create Input / Output Streams for communication with the client
            while(true)
            {
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sslSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(
                            sslSocket.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine, outputLine;

            System.out.println("Start reading socket");

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                 //out.println(inputLine);
                 System.out.println(inputLine);
            }

            System.out.println("Finished reading socket");

            // Send the response
            // Send the headers
            out.println("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
            out.println("Content-Type: text/html");
            out.println("Server: Bot");
            // this blank line signals the end of the headers
            out.println("");
            // Send the HTML page
            out.println("<H1>Welcome to the Ultra Mini-WebServer</H2>");
            out.flush();

            // Close the streams and the socket
            out.close();
            in.close();
            sslSocket.close();
            sslServerSocket.close();

            }
        }


    catch(Exception exp)
    {
        PrivilegedActionException priexp = new PrivilegedActionException(exp);
        System.out.println(" Priv exp --- " + priexp.getMessage());

        System.out.println(" Exception occurred .... " +exp);
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

As I said, I've tried a bunch of other example programs that are similar, and they all seem to fail at the same area, after the read of the request.

NOTE that if I use openssl s_client and type the same input request in manually it works.

Can anyone help point me to what might be wrong?

Thanks,
Jim

EDIT:

I think that I've made some progress, with a different example server code, the one from here:

http://www.herongyang.com/JDK/HTTPS-Server-Test-Program-HttpsHello.html

First of all, again, if I run this app and hit it from "openssl s_client", it works fine when I manually enter a "GET".

But, if I try using Firefox, as soon as I send a request to https://192.168.0.6:8888 (FYI, doesn't matter if I use a hostname that matches cert), I get a popup asking me to add an exception and ALSO, I get at the app/server end:

```
Server started:
Server socket class: class sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl
   Socket address = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
   Socket port = 8888
   Need client authentication = false
   Want client authentication = false
   Use client mode = false
Socket class: class sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl
   Remote address = /192.168.0.5
   Remote port = 58972
   Local socket address = /192.168.0.5:8888
   Local address = /192.168.0.5
   Local port = 8888
   Need client authentication = false
   Cipher suite = SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL
   Protocol = NONE
Read=[null]
java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at HttpsHello.main(HttpsHello.java:43)
```

So, I did something differently.

I started Firefox, then went to Options->Advanced->Certificates->Add Exception

For the exception, I put the URL to get the cert, https://192.168.0.5:8888

The app blew up as soon as I clicked "Get Certificate":

```
Server started:
Server socket class: class sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl
   Socket address = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
   Socket port = 8888
   Need client authentication = false
   Want client authentication = false
   Use client mode = false
Socket class: class sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl
   Remote address = /192.168.0.5
   Remote port = 59018
   Local socket address = /192.168.0.5:8888
   Local address = /192.168.0.5
   Local port = 8888
   Need client authentication = false
   Cipher suite = SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL
   Protocol = NONE
Read=[null]
java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
    at HttpsHello.main(HttpsHello.java:43)
```

BUT, Firefox let me add a temporary exception at this point!!

Ok, then after adding the temporary exception, I restarted the app, and put in https://192.168.0.5:8888 into the Firefox address, and, at that point, IT WORKED, i.e., I got the "Hello world" web page in Firefox!!

Does anyone know why this is happening?  Why is it that "openssl s_client" works, but it blows up with Firefox, APPARENTLY when Firefox is getting the cert from the app to add the cert as an exception?

EDIT 2:

I posted in comments that I got this working on one of my laptops, but I still haven't gotten it working on my main development machine.

I am pasting in the SSL debug log from a test I just did at:

http://pastebin.com/faVCjj3a

If anyone can see anything that might be causing this please let me know?  I did this test after moving over the exact JKS file and certs from the working system.  Also, I've installed the unlimited strength policy jars on this other system.

Thanks...

EDIT 3:  I think I've finally found an example that seems to work:

http://www.mybinarylife.net/2012/06/java-ssl-threaded-echo-server.html

I modified that code slightly to send HTTP response instead of just echoing the request, and it seems to work even with a browser like Firefox.

It appears that the difference between hitting the server with openssl s_client and a browser is that when the first request is made, and the browser finds some problem like the hostname not matching the cert or other situations, and when the browser like Firefox is asking for an exception, there is an SSL error, so the server has to be able to handle that and continue handling the request/connection, rather than just dying, which this new example seems to do.

Comment: can u also publish your client code that is trying to connect to your server socket? I suspect the issue is with your client code.

Comment: Hi - For the "client side", I have been using "openssl s_client" and different browsers, mainly Firefox.  As I said, the strange thing is if I use "openssl s_client" I can connect and send data to my SSL server code, but when I use a browser like Firefox to hit the same SSL server code, it is failing.  Also like I said, it seems to be receiving the request but then fails at the point that it is trying to send a response to the client side.

Comment: The answer is simple: The certificate you use is self-signed and therefore not trusted by Firefox. openssl s_client does only warn in case of untrusted certificates. Trusting (or not) an certificate is the fundamental basis of SSL/TLS.

Comment: Robert - The JKS I'm using has my CA cert and the server cert/key pair (signed by that CA) in it.  The CA cert is marked as trustcacerts.  I have that same CA cert in the Trusted Authorities in the Firefox.  What else do I need to do?

Comment: FYI, I also tried adding the CA cert to the c:\program files (x86)\java\jrex\lib\security\cacerts as trustcacerts, but still get the same problem.  I don't understand why those examples apparently work for others but I am having this problem?

Comment: I think that the server cert I have is using md5 hash, because I use a small CA app that is very old.  Would the server cert containing an MD5 hash cause this problem?

Comment: FYI, I was  able to get this working on ONE of my environments, on my laptop, where I had Eclipse running on the laptop and hit it from a Firefox on the laptop.  To get it working, I used openssl to create a new CA and server cert and key.  Then I used Key Explorer to put the server cert and key and the CA cert into a new JKS.  As part of getting Key Explorer to work, I had to install the unlimited policy JARs.  After that the app above seems to work.  I have to try to get my main development machine working, but at least I might be able to use this to compare.

Comment: Another thing that I think makes a difference whether it works or not is that , for the HTTP request/URL, I was using a hostname that matched the CN of the server cert.  I will need to try to see if this all makes a difference when I get home.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments, but I found that it only works with Firefox and not with IE or Chrome :(...

Comment: Correction to my last comment about IE and Chrome not working - it appears that they are working, but not if the URL uses the hostname.  If I use the IP address in the URL, then they work now also.  IE and Chrome might be caching the DNS resolutions or something?

Comment: Alos check if your self-signed cert has IP or full hostname in it...the cert is validated against your url.